# Rotate Text Geometry around a special point in three.js

Tags: math, vector, three.js

Please check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wPxu.png)

When I try to rotate text geometry in three.js, it procceds around left-bottom point by default. (Red point in the image)

However, I'd like to rotate it around the its center point of gravity, or any special point. (Blue point in the image)

It seems some Math trick will be needed, or any three.js API for this?
Hope your help.

Comment: Have a look in the documentation about [.center()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Geometry.center).

Comment: Wow, why don't you post this? I will accept this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rotate a geometry around its center point of gravity, then you can use the [`.center()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Geometry.center) method of the geometry.

If you want another point of rotation, then have a look at the [`.translate()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Geometry.translate) method.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I knew the methods before, but I tried them for 'Mesh' object, instead of 'Geometry' object. That was my fault. Thanks again.

Comment: @Luis You're welcome :) `THREE.BufferGeometry()` has those methods too.